# Not able to load class inside other class in rails -- TypeError: is not a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> I have two rails applications where inside the first one I have defined all the business logic and using "gem" in another one. When I am opening classes in other rails app to add some methods then it is not loading it giving **"TypeError: Restaurant is not a module"** code is given below:

app/models/invoices/restaurant/searchable.rb

```
module Invoices
  module Restaurant
    module Searchable
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern
      included do
        include Elasticsearch::Model
        index_name "restaurant-invoices-#{Rails.env}"
      end
    end
  end
end

# force load
Restaurant::Invoice.ancestors

module Restaurant
  class Invoice
    include ::Invoices::Restaurant::Searchable
  end
end
```

Invoice class inside other Rails app:

> app/models/restaurant/invoice.rb

```
class Restaurant::Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
   // here all business logic
end
```

> When I am running **Invoices::Restaurant::Searchable** then it throws an error **"TypeError: Restaurant is not a module"** I thought that its an issue with the "module Restaurant" so I have changed its name to "module Restaurant1" and then run "**Invoices::Restaurant1::Searchable**" again same issue. Could anyone help me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think that what ruby is trying to tell you here is that it already found a ```Restaurant``` somewhere and it is not a module. If you go to the project console and do ```Restaurant.class``` what does it say? If it says ```Class``` it means that you are declaring ```Restaurant``` somewhere (or rails is) as something different than a module.

Comment: `> Restaurant.class
 => Class`

It's showing class.

Answer (score 1):

When defining classes you should shouldn't use the shorthand. I think that the following code defines *Restaurant* as a class:

```
class Restaurant::Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  # here all business logic
end
```

If this code is loaded first, how is Ruby supposed to know if *Restaurant* is a class or module? Rails autoloading creates missing classes and modules. This will most likely be your problem. See: [Autoloading and Reloading Constants - Common Gotchas](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants_classic_mode.html#common-gotchas)

Only use the `::` to reference classes, not create them. You can also find this in the [Ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition). Change the above code to:

```
module Restaurant
  class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
    # here all business logic
  end
end
```

This might solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I have resolved it by adding below code:

```
class Restaurant::Invoice
  include ::Invoices::Restaurant::Searchable
end
```

Comment: By changing `module Restaurant; class Invoice; # ...` to `class Restaurant::Invoice; # ...` you're letting Rails decide what type *Restaurant*, will be (*Class* or *Module*). This will indeed also solve your issue, if you don't care what *Restaurant* is this is fine. Otherwise I recommend trying my given solution.